# OnDrop Event never fired for Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, webkit

I am building a website specifically for the iPad. I am attempting to get drag & drop to work but the ondrop event seems to never fire for some reason.

**Can you help me get the div to detect when I drop an element on top of it?**

I have a very simple HTML page that demonstrates that the ondrop event is never fired in Safari. This fails in both desktop safari & ipad safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <style  type="text/css">
    <!--
        body {
            margin: 100px;
        }

        .dropTarget {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px; 
            float: left;
            display: inline;
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: green;
            -webkit-user-drop: element;
        }

        .drag {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px; 
            background-color: red;
            -webkit-user-drag: element; /*element*/
        }

    -->
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function onDrop(e, ele) { alert("drop"); }
    -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="drag">
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div class="dropTarget" ondrop="onDrop(e,this);">
    </div>
    <br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to cancel the `dragover` event's default action before you can use the `drop` event for something, otherwise the browser ignores it.

Change your dropTarget `<div>` from this:

```
<div class="dropTarget" ondrop="onDrop(e,this);">
```

To this:

```
<div class="dropTarget" ondragover="return false;" ondrop="onDrop(event,this);">
```

If you use inline event registration you have to use `event` to pass the event instead of `e`.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason might be:

In reference with the [drag-and-drop-processing-model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#drag-and-drop-processing-model), the drop event surprisingly does not get fired if the platform is changing the e.dataTransfer.dropEffect which ([preferably should match](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/DragAndDrop.html)) is not matching with e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed property of the event.

[image]